# React Native: Unable to push notification using Cloud Messaging API (Legacy) in Firebase

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have used this post https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/sending-notifications-custom/ to create push notification for React Native for Android.

Added this line in my React Native app:

```
const token = (await Notifications.getDevicePushTokenAsync()).data;
```

I used the legacy API of Firebase

```
await fetch('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: `key=<FCM-SERVER-KEY>`,
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    to: '<NATIVE-DEVICE-PUSH-TOKEN>',
    priority: 'normal',
    data: {
      experienceId: '@yourExpoUsername/yourProjectSlug',
      scopeKey: '@yourExpoUsername/yourProjectSlug',
      title: " You've got mail",
      message: 'Hello world! ',
    },
  }),
});
```

I got the API response as follows:

[image: Success API response]

**Edited:** Now, I am getting the following response (with failure):

```
{
    "multicast_id": 4724312561560578192,
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 1,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "error": "MismatchSenderId"
        }
    ]
}
```

But no push notification was sent to the physical mobile

What is missing to be able to receive push notification using an Expo app?

Comment: hello you put receive notification code in your app.js you need to check this https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/receiving-notifications/

Comment: I have already applied this documentation. Do I have to add something in AndroidManifest.xml or any other file after building react native app as an Android app; that is, after generating the "android" directory?